# How to replace repeated measurements with the mean, excluding the first measurement in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I can't seem to find any previous similar questions.

Here is my data:

[image: DF1]

```
ID <- c(3,3,3,3,3,3,5,5,5,5)
Measurement <- c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 19, 6, 6, 6, 7)
BP <- c(14, 14, 15, 16, 14, 13, 14, 17, 18, 20)
BP2 <- c(7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 7, 8, 9)
DF1 <- data.frame(ID, Measurement, BP, BP2)
```

For cases where there are multiple measurements per ID, I would like to remove the first instance, and then find the mean of the remaining associated BPs and BP2s for that measurement.

This is what I would like the data to look like:

[image: DF2]

I hope that makes sense, any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative `dplyr` approach would be

```r
library(dplyr)

DF1 %>% 
  group_by(ID, Measurement) %>%
  summarise_all(~if(length(.x) == 1) .x else mean(.x[-1]))
#># A tibble: 4 x 4
#># Groups:   ID [2]
#>     ID Measurement    BP   BP2
#>  <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>1     3           2  14.8   8.5
#>2     3          19  13    11  
#>3     5           6  17.5   7.5
#>4     5           7  20     9
```

Answer (score 2):

You could `filter` per `group_by` by checking if the group has more than 1 row using `n()` and `row_number` to remove the first row and `summarise` with `across` to calculate the `mean` value like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
DF1 %>%
  group_by(ID, Measurement) %>%
  filter(!(n() > 1 & row_number() == 1)) %>%
  summarise(across(BP:BP2, ~ mean(.x)))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'ID'. You can override using the `.groups`
#> argument.
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>      ID Measurement    BP   BP2
#>   <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     3           2  14.8   8.5
#> 2     3          19  13    11  
#> 3     5           6  17.5   7.5
#> 4     5           7  20     9
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

a `data.table` approach can be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF1)[, if(.N>1) .SD[2:.N] else .SD, by=ID
           ][, lapply(.SD, mean), by = .(ID, Measurement)]
#    ID Measurement    BP  BP2
# 1:  3           2 14.75  8.5
# 2:  3          19 13.00 11.0
# 3:  5           6 17.50  7.5
# 4:  5           7 20.00  9.0
```